# How do I display box-plots of different data sets above each other in R?

Tags: r, graph, boxplot

new to R and just wondering is it possible to display these two box plots either side by side or above each other to allow for comparison, rather then producing two seperate box plots.

```
PBe <- PB$`Enterococci (cfu/100ml)`
BRe <- BR$`Enterococci (cfu/100ml)`
boxplot(BRe, horizontal = TRUE, col = "3", outline=FALSE)

boxplot(PBe, horizontal = TRUE, col = "4", outline=FALSE)
```

Answer (score 2):

You could use the `boxplot` function directly:

```
boxplot(list(BRe = BRe, PBe = PBE), col = c(3, 4))
```

You could add all the other parameters as you wish

Answer (score 0):

We obviously don't have your data, so let's make a minimal reproducible example.

First we create two data frames, one called `PB` and one called `BR`. Each has a numeric column called `Enterococci (cfu/100ml)` containing random numbers between 100 and 1000:

```r
set.seed(1)
PB <- data.frame(a = sample(100:1000, 100, TRUE))
BR <- data.frame(a = sample(100:1000, 50, TRUE))
names(PB) <- "Enterococci (cfu/100ml)"
names(BR) <- "Enterococci (cfu/100ml)"
```

Now, if we extract these columns as per your code, we can concatenate them together using `c`

```
PBe <- PB$`Enterococci (cfu/100ml)`
BRe <- BR$`Enterococci (cfu/100ml)`
value <- c(PBe, BRe)
```

Now, the trick is to create another vector that labels which data frame these numbers originally came from as a factor variable. We can do that with:

```
dataset <- factor(c(rep("PB", nrow(PB)), rep("BR", nrow(BR))))
```

And now we can just call `plot` on these two vectors. This will automatically give us a side-by-side boxplot:

```r
plot(dataset, value, xlab = "Data set", ylab = "Enterococci (cfu/100ml)")
```

[image]

If you would prefer it to be horizontal, we can do:

```r
boxplot(value ~ dataset, horizontal = TRUE,
        ylab = "Data set", 
        xlab = "Enterococci (cfu/100ml)")
```

[image]

Comment: although when I added more data sets the names jumbled up and aren't under neath the right box plot.